# Mask Text is missing, when Setting .val(null) or .val('')

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I'm using a date format, which naturally only allows numbers. I set up some shortcuts on such fields where 'd' or 't' defaults to current datetime, and 'c' clears back to null.

When clearing via `.val(null)` or `val('')`, the text box ends up completely empty - the inputmask plugin doesn't automatically replenish the mask.

This is likely a bug, but I would like a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation mentions](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/wiki/HOWTO:-Best-ways-to-set-a-value-for-an-inputmask.):

> set the value by using the value property and after that trigger the
>   setvalue event

Looking in the source code, I found this refers to

```
.triggerHandler("setvalue.inputmask")
```

But that didn't work. However, if I click off and then on again, the mask would be replenished. Therefore I added the following code after assigning the value:

```
$(element).val(dateString); // Assigning the value
if (dateString === null && $(element).is(":focus")) // If already focused
{
    $(element).focus(); // Refocus to replenish mask
}
```